# Button in Phaser doesn't work on some versions of iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, phaser-framework

So we have this simple game created in Phaser that exhibits the following behavior.

We have a button that works on every device, except for a device with the following User Agent String: **Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS_10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E277 Safari/602.1**

When a user with this user agent clicks the button, nothing happens. They supplied us with screenshots and the page seems to have rendered just fine, it's just the button that doesn't trigger anything.

The button is created like this:

```
Ball.MainMenu.prototype = {
create: function() {
    //this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'screen-mainmenu');

    this.startButton = this.add.button(Ball._WIDTH*0.5, 1000, 'button-start', this.startGame, this, 2, 0, 1);
    this.startButton.anchor.set(0.5,0);
    this.startButton.scale.setTo(0.75,0.75);
    this.startButton.input.useHandCursor = true;
},
startGame: function () {
    window.showHowTo();
}
};
```

and the window.showHowTo()-function is located in another file (plain javascript), and looks like this:

```
 function showHowTo() {
        $("#howto").show();
 }
```

It really just shows a div and nothing more.

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?